# How to remove a mutable and static (global) variable from recursive rust function in order to prevent unsafe use?

Tags: rust

Currently I am writing an eval function for an abstract syntax tree in rust (but that's really not important to the problem), where I am using match statements and recursion to evalute it. The Dup node should return the last value entered by the user (which is given by the last evaluted input node). Here is the function in question:

```rust
static mut LAST: Option<i32>; 

fn eval(ast: AST) -> i32 {
    match ast {
        AST::Operator(op, left, right) => {
            let left_value = eval(*left);
            let right_value = eval(*right);
            
            match op {
                Ops::Mul => left_value * right_value,
            }
        }
        AST::Input => {
            // Prompt the user for input until a valid integer is entered
            loop {
                let mut input = String::new();
                std::io::stdin()
                    .read_line(&mut input)
                    .expect("Failed to read input");
                match input.trim().parse::<i32>() {
                    Ok(value) => {
                        unsafe { LAST = Some(value) };
                        break value
                    },
                    Err(_) => println!("Invalid input! Please enter a valid integer."),
                }
            }
        }
        AST::Dup => {

            unsafe { LAST.unwrap() }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in order to share state between the Input and Dup nodes I am using a static and mutable variable which requires `unsafe` rust. I want to rewrite this without using unsafe and with the state of LAST only being available inside fn eval (its lifetime should be created and destroyed when eval() is finished)

First thing I tried was a variable inside the function body, but the function is recursive so the value dies as soon as the AST::Input branch returns and is not propagated up the recursion tree. Next thing I tried was adding a parameter to the function, but this only works if I am sending state down the tree, but AST::Input is always a leaf node so we have to send state back up the tree.

Comment: What purpose does this global serve vs. having a local you return? I can't see why this is shared between calls.

Comment: You could also return an `Option<i32>` and then `match (op, left_value, right_value)` to test for `(Ops::Mul, Some(l), Some(r)) => l * r` with an `_ => panic!("...")`.

Comment: @tadman it's because of the recursion in the AST::Operator branch. AST::Input maybe handled in `eval(*left)` while AST::Dup maybe handled in `eval(*right)`

Comment: If there's some parent call context required, pass it in as an argument. Don't go down the global road unless there is absolutely no other way. `fn eval(ast: AST, last: Option<i32>)` is an easy fix.

Comment: @tadman that doesn't work because `last` is not known until the function recurses and matches to an AST::Input where user the inputs the data.

Comment: Maybe what you need is to separate this into two problems: Reading/tokenizing and processing if you're getting tripped up on the input part. Passing in a mutable stream which not only implements `next()` but `last()` could solve this problem.

Comment: This is orthogonal to the question, but it would be preferable to have better error handling than `unwrap`. One option would be to have the function return an `Option<i32>` instead of an `i32`, since it's possible that evaluating the function fails to produce an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals almost always can be substituted by just making the global in question a parameter of the function, if communication has to go both ways, make it a reference:

```rust
enum AST {
    Mul(Box<AST>, Box<AST>),
    Input,
    Dup,
}

fn eval(ast: AST, mut last: &mut Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    match ast {
        AST::Mul(left, right) => {
            let left_value = eval(*left, last);
            let right_value = eval(*right, last);
            left_value * right_value
        }
        AST::Input => {
            // Prompt the user for input until a valid integer is entered
            use rand::Rng;
            let value = rand::thread_rng().gen();
            *last = Some(value);
            value
        }
        AST::Dup => {
            last.unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by tracking state in both the method signature and the return type and handling the state management before the recursive calls. Though it seems cafce25's answer is cleaner.

```rust
fn eval(ast: AST, last: Option<i32>) -> (i32, Option<i32>) {
    match ast {
        AST::Operator(op, left, right) => {
            let left = eval(*left, last);
            let right = eval(*right, left.1);
            let (left_value, right_value) = (left.0, right.0);

            let res = left.1.or_else(|| right.1);

            let result = match op {
                Ops::Mul => left_value * right_value,
            };

            (result, res)
        }
        AST::Input => {
            loop {
                let mut input = String::new();
                std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read input");
                if let Ok(value) = input.trim().parse::<i32>() {
                    break (value, Some(value));
                } else {
                    println!("Invalid input! Please enter a valid integer.");
                }
            }
        }
        AST::Dup => {
            match last {
                Some(value) => (value, Some(value)),
                None => panic!("Cannot dup without a previous value"),
            }
        }
    }
}
```